# Excel VBA skip footers and headers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that writes data to an excel spreadsheet formatted as A4 pages. How do I build a macro that skips the footers and headers of each page? Currently my data is writing from A1:A500 for example, but i would like the data to be written from A10:A50, A65 to A105, A120 to A160 and so on. This would prevent the data from overlapping with the footers and headers.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm kinda lost on the entire idea. The only way i see doing this is naming the ranges somehow and making multiple ifs... e.g. "if selected cell on footer rows 30-40 then select row a45. This is just a horrible way of doing this for tens of pages.

Comment: When you say "formatted as A4 pages", are you trying to Print it?  The Print screen should let you configure things with regards the Header, Footer, and how much data per page in that case.  If you're not trying to print it, why A4, and not screen-sized?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to convert old row number to new row number

```vb
Function A4_Row(n As Long) As Long
    A4_Row = 9 + n + Int((n - 1) / 41) * 14
End Function

Sub Demo()
   Dim i As Long, j As Long
   For i = 1 To 500
      j = A4_Row(i)
      Cells(i, 1) = i
      Cells(i, 2) = j
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this solution. Is this some "standard" math of excel to identify footers and headers in the function and then adjust my range accordingly? What is going on in this?

Comment: @Carlsberg Yes, If you are currently writing to `Range("A" & r)` where r is 1 to 500 then just change to `Range("A" & A4_Row(r))`

Comment: I tested the vba code you put but, but it is writing on header and footer. I have set up my header and footer as just images (although by using standard excel header and  footers)

Comment: @Carlsberg You need to post your code (and maybe a screenshots) so I can reproduce your problem.